# Filter data before plotting Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to make a bar plot of a variable against another, and only show the bars that are above a threshold.

My code:

```
df.groupby('var1')['var2'].sum().where(lambda x : x > 100).plot.bar()
```

This produces a plot where the bars below the threshold disappear, but are still shown in the x-axis.

How do I make the filtered categories are no longer shown?

Answer (score 2):

You can filter the result of groupby and plot

```
df_sum = df.groupby('var1')['var2'].sum()
df_sum[df_sum > 100].plot.bar()
```